# Не получается переменная

Tags: php

Знает кто, в чем проблема? р в этой строчке: if ($_GET['p']) почему-то не видится.. я не понимаю..

Весь код страницы:

```
<?php
    $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `quote`");
    if (!$select) die ('Error'. mysqli_error($connect));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
    $count_post = $row [0];

    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");  
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `discription`, `author`, `data` FROM `quote` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number = 0;

    if (!$_GET)
    {
        while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    ?>
            <div class="card news border-dark mb-3" style="min-width: 100%;">
                <div class="card-header">Quotes</div>
                    <div class="card-body text-dark">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-checker" id="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                        <div class="limiter">       
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $news['id']; ?></h5>              
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['author']; ?></p>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['discription']; ?></p>
                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['data']; ?></p>
                            <div class="bottom"></div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" class="read-more-button"></label>
                    </div>  
            </div>
            <?php
            $number = $number + 1;
        }
        

    echo "Page 1 ";
    }

    for ($i = 2, $ii = 2; $i < $count_post; $i = $i + 2, $ii ++)
    echo "<a href = 'index.php?p={$i}'> {$ii} </a>";

    if ($_GET['p'])
    {
        $page = (int) $_GET['p'];
        $query = "SELECT `id`, `discription`, `author`, `data` FROM `quote` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $page,2";
        while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
?>
        
        <div class="card news border-dark mb-3" style="min-width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-header">Quotes</div>
                <div class="card-body text-dark">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-checker" id="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                    <div class="limiter">       
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $news['id']; ?></h5>              
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['author']; ?></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['discription']; ?></p>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['data']; ?></p>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <label for="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" class="read-more-button"></label>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <?php
            $number = $number + 1;

    echo "Page <a href = 'index.php?p={$i}'> 1 </a>";
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Так а в URL этот GET у вас установлен?

Comment: Я вероятно туплю, но если я пытаюсь вставить его в ссылку, то получаю неопознанную р там

Comment: покажите ссылку, находясь на которой вы ожидаете что скрипт увиди ваш GET

Comment: Так. Я не совсем понимаю. вот сюда нужно чтоб передавалось р, чтоб менялся номер страницы.  
 echo "<a href = 'index.php?p={$i}'> {$ii} </a>";
echo "Page <a href = 'index.php?p={$i}'> 1 </a>"; 

Собственно, везде, где есть р. Я смотрела некоторые видео, но у них работало..

Comment: Это вы пагинацию делаете? пробуйте ```<a href = 'index.php?p=<?=$_GET['p']++ ?></a>```

Comment: Да, это попытки сделать пагинацию..:)

Либо я просто  как-то не так сделала, либо это не помогло: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Я уже пыталась так вставить get ранее, у меня не вышло.. тоже выдавалась ошибка

Comment: Покажите что у вас в адресной строке браузера

Comment: До нажатия куда-либо: http://localhost/quotes/index.php                            

После нажатия: http://localhost/quotes/index.php?p=2                   

предупреждение уходит. Только проблема еще и в том, что записи на странице не меняются. В общем, как я поняла вся пагинация кривая, но я не понимаю, как это тогда исправить.. Все это в целом странно работает...

Comment: https://sun9-87.userapi.com/impg/LLlIc_uCZ0Zqjz04U4nxOkQKsjqs91gP7zuTKw/6rfZL2i3xh8.jpg?size=604x340&quality=96&sign=17f0d473cfc53553b4504aab01030490&type=album

https://sun9-71.userapi.com/impg/hbfcvBagTNzvp5xTyOV3kWrXqej_ft5DHSwS8Q/8ydWXfKATgY.jpg?size=604x340&quality=96&sign=32a3b96cb23d33682ed3d601f80c52fc&type=album

Comment: @Neko Вы слишком много кода пишете. Ветка для первой страницы просто лишняя. Запишите страницу в переменную `$page = $_GET['p'] ?? 1;` и работайте универсально. Потом пагинация кривая, да: лимиты не выдают ничего по страницам, Вам нужно умножать количество на страницу и отдавать в лимит числа диапазона ([с какого элемента начать],[до какого элемента брать]). Ошибка "Unexpected index p" возникает из-за того, что в массиве нет индекса, нуобходимо оборачивать в `!empty($_GET['p'])` или использовать nullish coalescing (по сути переменная, о которой я сказал, избавит Вас от ошибки).

Comment: @Neko И отделяйте представления от бизнес-логики, в этой каше разобраться очень сложно...

Comment: Да, я решила снести все и написать иначе. мне кажется вышло лучше. Отвечу на вопрос свой.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Надо было просто написать нормально сразу, ахаха. Хотя я не уверена, что написала лучше, по крайней мере код не повторяется

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? (int) $_GET["page"] : 1;

    $notesOnPage = 3;

    $from = ($page - 1) * $notesOnPage;

    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");  
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `discription`, `author`, `data` FROM `quote` WHERE id > 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from, $notesOnPage";
    //var_dump($query);
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number = 0;

    while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
?>

<div class="card news border-dark mb-3" style="min-width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-header">Quotes</div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-checker" id="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" />
            <div class="limiter">       
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $news['id']; ?></h5>              
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['author']; ?></p>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['discription']; ?></p>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $news['data']; ?></p>
                <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <label for="read-more-checker-<?php echo $number; ?>" class="read-more-button"></label>
        </div>  
</div>

<?php
        $number = $number + 1;
    }

    $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `quote`");
    if (!$select) die ('Error'. mysqli_error($connect));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
    $count_post = $row [0];

    $pages_count = ceil ($count_post / $notesOnPage);
    //var_dump($pages_count);
?>
    <div class="pagination">
<?php

    for($i = 1; $i < $pages_count; $i++){
        echo "<a href =\"?page=$i\">$i </a>";
    }
?>
</div>
```